# delete matrix entries to make it nonsingular

Tags: matrices

I have a binary matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\{0,1\})$ which is singular and with no zero columns or rows. I was wandering, assume I can set arbitrarily some of the entries of $A$ to zero, is there any efficient way to choose these entries of $A$ to set to zero in such a way to obtain a matrix whose first $r$ columns are some permutation of any subset of dimension $r$ of the columns of the identity, and such matrix is so that $r$ is the maximal number of columns I can obtain having this property (i.e. to be the some permutation of any $r$-dimensional subset of the set of the columns of the identity)?
For instance assume I have
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\0&0&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
which is obviously nonsingular. setting $A_{12}$ to zero I obtain a nonsingular matrix, moreover by setting to zero also $A_{31}, A_{13}, A_{33}$ I finally obtain matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 &1\\0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Example 2 (thanks to John Hughes)
consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ In this case I can get only two columns with the above property, thus $r=2$ and for instance by eliminating $A_{11},A_{13},A_{14},A_{31},A_{41}$ I obtain $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ which has the desired property and $r=2$ is maximal

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider the matrix

```
1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0
```

No "deleted" version of this matrix (i.e., with some 1s changed to 0s) is nonsingular. And, of course, there's no way to "delete" stuff to get a permuted identity, either. Your hypotheses just aren't strong enough.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have reformulate the question. Thanks